# Isolating Admin from User login windows app form to Database C#

Tags: c#, database, authentication, authorization

)

I'm having a bit of a problem separating a normal user login from an admin login.

the admin should see * data in the DB, and freely change any data s/he wants while a user may only see the allowed data without editing them.

and is there a way to set the permission within the DB ITSELF?

Thank you in previous.

Comment: You need to decide (and describe) what you want to do. If you are using SQL Server with "Windows Integrated Security", then you will/can use the user's token (reflected in the process token) when accessing the database. The database can provide the security. If you are writing a web application then will likely be unable to do that, and you will need to decide what authentication/authorization mechanism you want to use

Comment: Integrated security is not an option here mate because the DB will be centralized and like 200k users can access it. any other tips you can give me?

Comment: By the way, information like that should really be in the question. For all I know, from what's in your question, this could be a simple desktop app, perhaps using MS Access. You don't mention the database you are using, you don't mention desktop versus web, you don't mention frameworks (Web Forms, MVC, Angular client with REST to the back end), number of users. By the way you likely want a somewhat more granular set of roles than just admin/user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest implementation would be `Role-Based Login`. You can save the role attribute in your user table and read it each time users login. Here is a sample implementation:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/role-based-user-login-with-switch-case-in-windows-app-in-c-sharp

For more granular access and more complicated permission we can use `Controls Based Security`. This makes role permission editable through the database. Sample implementation:

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/windows-forms/controls-based-security-in-a-windows-forms-application/

Comment: Thank you for the solution @Wildan Muhlls, you saved my day. I like the switch case approach but binding Roles, Users and Controls through multi foreign keys seems much neater. I will try ( Apply the solution} catch{ Help if needed} thank you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish users (admin/user) by adding a field in Users table.
For example if `IsAdmin` field is `true` then the logged in user is admin and you can give him editing permissions in your windows app.

When user logs in you can save his status (IsAdmin) in a global variable.

This is the simplest way.